# how to run through a linked list and print only what contains a certain data then run through it again to print what contains another data in c?

Tags: c, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

i'm a beginner in programming and i have this program that i have to do : so basically " an appointment in a doctor's office program"
i neary finished but a have a function that i have a problem with which is going to print the waiting list of patients : those who have an appointment are printed first then those who don't have an appointment are printed next .
i used obviously a doubly linked list which containts n number of patients information .the information contains besides the personal one ,if the patient who came have an appointment or not .if he does he has a number >0 (first person who has an appointment gets 1)if not then a number <0(first person who doesn't have an appointment gets -1)
this is the function but is seems to only print the first on a list ! please if you know the problem tell me.

```
    void waiting(void)
{
    currentc=firstc;
    while (currentc->next!=NULL)
    {
        currentc=currentc->next;
    }
    while(currentc!=NULL)
    {
        if(currentc->prio>0)
        {printf("%6d: %-20s %-6s %-15s %-20s %-8s %-8d\n",\
                currentc->number,\
                currentc->name,\
                currentc->age,\
                currentc->phone,\
                currentc->numcin,\
                currentc->state,\
                currentc->prio);
        }

       currentc=currentc->prev;
    }
    currentc=firstc;
    while (currentc->next!=NULL)
    {
        currentc=currentc->next;
    }

    while(currentc!=NULL)
    {
        if(currentc->prio<0)
        {printf("%6d: %-20s %-6s %-15s %-20s %-8s %-8d\n",\
                currentc->number,\
                currentc->name,\
                currentc->age,\
                currentc->phone,\
                currentc->numcin,\
                currentc->state,\
                currentc->prio);
        }

       currentc=currentc->prev;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal, reproducible example, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: Your loops _will_ print stuff [in _reverse_ order] _if_ `prio` is _either_ `>0` or `<0` but _not_ if it _is_ zero. So, please _edit_ your question and post more of your code as the problem may be elsewhere. (e.g.) setup of `prio` value or the `prev` and/or `next` members are incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

If you are printing the only the first node, it means that your list is not linked. The code you share is okay for traversing.

Comment: i have a function that lists all the patients information and it works just fine . I'm still lost and can't find the problem

Comment: Let me summarize what your code is doing. First it goes while the next one is not the null. It reaches to the end. From there, it goes backwards and prints if patient has appointment. Then, it sets currentc as prev and according to what you say, it stops. This means that while you are linking the nodes, you linked the next ones but you didn't link the prev ones. Can you show the code where you link them?